# How can I use the Factory pattern to refactor my Java code?

Tags: java, refactoring

I would like to use the Factory pattern to make a new method addShip this determines in running time which type of Ship to initialize.

```
    while(!g.allShipsPlaced())
    {
        NumberGenerator gen = new NumberGenerator();
        int x = gen.rand(10);
        int y = gen.rand(10);
        int o = gen.rand(1);

        x = gen.rand(10);
        y = gen.rand(10);
        o = gen.rand(2);        
        System.out.println("vertical sub x = " + x + "\n");
        System.out.println("vertical sub y = " + y + "\n");
        g.addSub(x,y, o);

        x = gen.rand(10);
        y = gen.rand(10);
        o = gen.rand(2);        
        System.out.println("vertical battle x = " + x + "\n");
        System.out.println("vertical battle y = " + y + "\n");
        g.addBattle(x,y, o);    

        x = gen.rand(10);
        y = gen.rand(10);
        o = gen.rand(2);                
        System.out.println("vertical air x = " + x + "\n");
        System.out.println("vertical air y = " + y + "\n");
        g.addAir(x,y, o);

        x = gen.rand(10);
        y = gen.rand(10);
        o = gen.rand(2);                
        System.out.println("vertical mine x = " + x + "\n");
        System.out.println("vertical mine y = " + y + "\n");
        g.addMine(x,y, o);

        x = gen.rand(10);
        y = gen.rand(10);
        o = gen.rand(2);
        System.out.println("horizontal dest x = " + x + "\n");
        System.out.println("horizontal dest y = " + y + "\n");
        g.addDest(x,y, o);

    }

    System.out.println("agent grid");
    System.out.println(g.toString());

    return g;
}
```

For example,

```
    x = gen.rand(10); 
    y = gen.rand(10);
    o = gen.rand(2);        
    System.out.println("vertical sub x = " + x + "\n");
    System.out.println("vertical sub y = " + y + "\n");
    g.addShip(x, y, o, "Submarine");
    /* x,y are the coordinates to define where to place the ship and o
    defines how to place the ship (horizontal or vertical) */
```

From the String type you can see which type of boat should be initialized, this would mean that you make a call to the addSubmarine method

Here is a link to the original code https://github.com/michaelokarimia/battleships/tree/master/Battleships. You can find this code in the Agent class. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use an `enum` and a `switch`.

Comment: What stops you from creating such a method? As you say, you can pass a String to determine the type. Inside, using if-else/switch on the type passed, call the appropriate method while passing along the values.

Comment: There is a lot of ship related stuff happening in your code other than creation of ships. For instance, the Grid class has a lot of duplicate code for each ship that first needs to be generalized. This is a big task and IMO cannot be answered without actually refactoring the entire code for you. The best way forward is to identify duplicate code and start generalizing it. Only then can you think of the factory pattern.

Comment: @bot Can you please give me any suggestions about how to generalize the code in Grid class? Any pattern or maybe you have some better recommendations ?

Comment: @Claire Don't worry about patterns at the moment. Just observe your Grid class and identify code that is duplicated. Then think of moving this code to a new class in a way that you can call it from anywhere in your application. This can be achieved by inheritance or composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Factory pattern in your code, you should do the following:

1. Extend all your `Ship` classes from abstract class `Ship`.
2. Create an abstract class `AbstractShipFactory` which has a method `Ship createShip(int, int, int)`.
3. Create concrete classes like `BattleShipFactory`, `DestShipFactory`, etc, which extend `AbstractShipFactory` and override `createShip`.
4. Use factories in your code:

   ```
   while(!g.allShipsPlaced())
   {
       NumberGenerator gen = new NumberGenerator();
       AbstractShipFactory battleFactory = new BattleShipFactory();
       ...
       g.addShip(battleFactory.createShip(gen.rand(), gen.rand(), gen.rand()));
       ...
   }
   ```

It's called *factory method*. Note that you must create new factory for every new product type.

Comment: Take a look at the entire code posted by the OP. There is a lot more work to be done. Lot more code to be generalized even before you can think of creating a factory.

Comment: How and where should I implement the addShip method (probably in the Grid class)?

 ` public Ship addShip(int i,int j,int s,String type)
 {
  Ship ship=factory.createShip(i, j, s, type);
  return ship;
 }
`

I thought of this but I have also a problem in the concrete classes that extend the AbstractShipFactory: 
` public class BattleFactory extends AbstractShipFactory{
                @Override
  public Ship createShip(int x, int y, int o, String type) {
   Ship ship;
   addBattle(x,y, o); //I don't know how to implement this method
   return ship;
  }
`

Comment: You shouldn't specify `String type` in `addShip` parameters. Your `addShip` method should have signature like `public void addShip(Ship ship)`, and all ship creation must be in concrete factories. Remove all `String type` from your code and use polymorphism.